# Reading a float from mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, floating-point, mysql-error-1064

I have two float variables that are equal, I retrieve them by PHP and subtract them. the result equals (7.105427357601E-15) I tried to change to double or to decimal and none of that worked. This is what I use in PHP:

```
$giftcard_balance = $giftcard['balance'];
$total = $product['price'];

$total -= $giftcard_balance;
echo $total;
```

Here instead of showing 0, it's showing (7.105427357601E-15)

Anyone can help please?

Comment: What values are in there typically?

Comment: Floats are not ordinal.  They also can't perfectly represent certain values.  You can't use == to compare floats or rely on subtracting a value from the same value resulting in 0.

Comment: What's the point in substracting identical values from another. The result is 0. The difference comes from float inaccuracy

Comment: use the round: `echo round($total,2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get rid of the float inaccuracy, you can, for example, use number formatting.

```
$a = 7.105427357601E-15;
$b = number_format($a, 2);
echo $a , "\n", $b , "\n";
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried the number_format and that solved the problem

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with prices and account balances you will find that DECIMAL(6, 2) is much easier to deal with than FLOAT. If you experience the same problem when using DECIMAL datatype please post a specific example.

Using `round()` or similar is a very bad idea as it is simply masking the problem, not fixing it.

Comment: There are cases when you're not in the position to change FLOAT to DECIMAL. In such cases rounding to 2,4,6,etc can be a life saver, mainly if it represents money.

Comment: @AttilaFulop - It's not a life saver, it's a bug waiting to rear its ugly head! Masking design mistakes like this is never a good idea. If the mistake has been made in the original design and there is a cost implication in fixing it, then stake holders need to be made aware of the possible implications of not fixing it. It is a battle than can almost always be won. I have been in that and similar situations more than once.

Comment: How would you solve it if you're having a webshop on Magento? That stores these values as FLOAT. If I change FLOAT to DECIMAL I'm breaking Magento. So I guess it only remains to solve it from php. Is there a better solution than rounding with a large enough precision?

Comment: What values are being stored as floats in Magento? This is not the first example of a poor design decision in Magento. It is often argued, incorrectly, that you need to use floats when dealing with currency conversion. It is important to have precise point in time values and these should be stored in DECIMAL not FLOAT.

Comment: Certain taxe rates are stored as FLOAT in Magento, rest is DECIMAL(12,4). But that's not the main problem. Checkout totals (subtotal, grand total, etc) are calculated internally as float within Magento. So for example if you apply a coupon that sets the grand total value to 0, then you actually have 7.105427357601E-15 instead of 0. I agree with you, that it's not ok to mask the problem, so that's why I'm asking, what is the proper solution in this case?

Comment: I have never used Magento so I cannot be sure how you would best fix the issue. I assume the issue is caused by PHP being loosely typed and it is casting to float implicitly. What is the value applied from the coupon that results in the float value? You should create a new question for this. Hopefully someone with experience of Magento will be able to suggest a solution.

Comment: I did resolve the problem with rounding to 4 decimals. I think it's not related to Magento but to php's float inaccuracy - exactly what this question is about. As you suggested it is not a good solution I thought you can recommend something better.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for the php `intval` [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php).

Or maybe the `round` [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php).

Comment: intval would be a mistake as intval("0.5") = 0